# Find oddly noted probability using pmf

Tags: probability

given PMF

$$p(x)\begin{cases} 
0.4^{x}/2,\quad x=0,1,2\\
c,\quad x=3\\
0,\quad otherwise
\end{cases}$$

using the definition of PMF I found $c=0.22$

what's required is to find 
$$P((x-1.5)^{2}\ge1)$$

I expanded the inside to yield

$$P((x^{2}-3x+9/2)\ge 1$$ 
Then factored to get  $$P((x(x-3)+9/2)\ge 1)$$
and then seperated the probabilities 
$$P(x+9/2)P(x-3)\ge 1$$

Not really sure in which direction to go about solving this problem...

As always any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
P((X-1.5)^2 \geq 1)&=P(X-1.5 \geq 1)+P(X-1.5 \leq -1)\\
&=P(X \geq 2.5)+P(X \leq 0.5) \\
&= P(X=3)+P(X=0) \\
&= c+ \frac12
\end{align}

Minor comments about your working:

- there is a mistake when you expand the quadratic term, rather than $\frac92$, it should be $\frac94$.
- the last step where you split the probabilities, I don't think you can do that. In fact, if the products of two probabilities is greater or equal to $1$, then each probability term has to be equal to $1$.